# Rename the Directory Index of a web page downloaded with wget to index.html

Tags: wget

I am currently using  a wget command that is fairly complicated, but the essence of it is the `-p` and `-k` flags to download all the pre-requisites. How do I rename the main downloaded file to index.html?

For instance, I download a webpage

```
http://myawesomewebsite.com/something/derp.html
```

This will, for example, download:

1. `derp.html`
2. `style.css`
3. `firstimage.png`
4. `secondimage.jpg`

And maybe even an iFrame:

1. `iframe.html`
2. `iframe-style.css`

So now the question is how do I rename `derp.html` to `index.html`, without accidentally renaming `iframe.html` to `index.html` as well, given that I don't know what the name of the resolved downloaded file may be?

When I tried this method on a Tumblr page with URL `http://something.tumblr.com/34324/post` it downloaded as `page.html`.

I've tried the `--output-document` flag, but that results in nothing being downloaded at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

If there was no `index.html` found after downloading, I used Ruby to get the `derp.html` part of the URL, and then searched for `derp.html` and then renamed it to `index.html`.

It's not as elegant as I would like, but it works.